# dataTable not able to paginate after reloading in meteor

Tags: jquery, html, meteor, datatable

i am using dataTables for designing and pagination of table in which data is loaded dynamically...i have created tr and td in javascript like

```
html = '<tr>'+
        '<td>'+req.product+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+createdAt+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+req.quantity+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+companyName+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+totQuot+'</td>'+
        '<td>'+totAppQuot+'</td>'+
        '<td><a class="imQuotCount" id="'+req._id+'_totQuot" href="">'+totImQuot+'</a></td>'+
        '<td><a class="imQuotCount" id="'+req._id+'_appQuot" href="">'+appImQuotCount+'</a></td>'+
        '<td><a class="imQuotCount" id="'+req._id+'_unappQuot" href="">'+unappImQuotCount+'</a></td>'+
        '<td><a class="imQuotCount" id="'+req._id+'_rejQuot" href="">'+rejImQuotCount+'</a></td>'+
    '</tr>'
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so i guessed that the problem was becoz of the data which was comming from database and it was my luck that my guess was right and all i did was in lib instead of directly writing Meteor.subscribe separately i returned all the Meteor.subscribe as array...and it worked